# checkdnsrr does not work for .edu email addresses?

Tags: php, email, validation

The following is the function I am using to validate a users email address when we add him (or her) to our system:

```
private function validate_email($email){
    list($userName, $mailDomain) = split("@", $email); 
    if (!checkdnsrr($mailDomain, "MX")) { //.edu does not work?
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

For some reason this function **always** seems to return false when I enter a `.edu` address that **I know** is valid.

How do I fix the function so it both validates and returns `true` for all email types?

Comment: My 2 cents: Get rid of validation altogether. Check that it conforms to `*@*` and throw everything else out the window. It's useless anyway - if you need to be sure a particular E-Mail address exists, you need to send a confirmation link anyway.

Comment: @Pekka -- we send a confirmation link, but we dont know if they received it or not, if we assume that the address is always valid, we cannot know if they got the confirmation...

Comment: getting the confirmation back is still the only way to go really. An E-Mail could go lost even if the address *is* valid due to overzealous spam filters. I maintain: Any validation beyond `*@*` is essentially pointless. Look at the new `.xyz` TLDs coming up... IDNs... Eventually, IDN TLDs....

Comment: @Pekka basically this is a employment candidate system where they would login and get the test for them to take. If we do not know that they did not get the email, we assume they did and they fail the test -- I **do not** want that to happen.

Comment: checkdnsrr just uses the system resolver. You can check that yourself by doing `nslookup -type=mx mit.edu` or `host -t mx mit.edu` from the command line to see if your dns setup is working.

Comment: @Neal I don't completely understand your situation, but to be clear: I'm just advocating not trusting the validation, but absolutely send a confirmation E-Mail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a hostname does not have an MX record, but does have an A (or AAAA) record, conforming mail transport agents will attempt delivery directly to the address given in the A record ([RFC 5321 section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5)):

> "If an empty list of MXs is returned,
> the address is treated as if it was associated with an implicit MX
> RR, with a preference of 0, pointing to that host."

Thus, the absence of an MX record does not necessarily indicate that mail cannot be delivered to that host.

---

**Addendum:** Much as Pekka says in the comments, the only reliable way to tell if an e-mail address is valid is to send mail to it and see if it gets delivered.  If you're worried about candidates trying to cheat by claiming that they didn't get the message, you could do something like this:

1. Ask for the candidate's e-mail address and send a confirmation message to it.  Include a confirmation link (and/or a confirmation code the candidate can enter in a form) in the message.
2. Once the candidate has confirmed that they've received the message by clicking the link, send them the actual test.

Comment: RE: your addendum -- a candidate still could claim that they did not get the test and then we would send out a new link, how would that work?

Comment: If they got the confirmation e-mail, you know the e-mail address they provided is correct and working.  That's as much confirmation as you can have.  What you want to do, if they still claim that they got the confirmation message but somehow didn't get the test, is then up to you.

Answer (score 1):

An MX record is actually not mandatory to receive email. If there is no MX record, standards-compliant MTAs will fall back to an A record if one is available. It's possible that some educational institutions are relying on this behavior; it's certainly not considered best practice, and it will lead to some mail delivery problems for them, but it *will* at least usually work.

Comment: The solution is implicit: Either remove the existing `checkdnsrr` check, or add a check for `A` records.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your edu provider does not let anyone see their dns records.

Comment: That's highly unlikely, especially for a domain that's being used for email.